# Why does $D\pi^i(p)(v)=v^i$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, tensor-products, differential-forms

There's an equality that I don't understand from Spivak' book "Calculus on Manifolds" (p. 89).

> We define 
>   $$ df(p)(v_p)=Df(p)(v) $$
>   Let us 
>   consider in particular the 1-forms $d\pi^i$. [...] 
>   $$ dx^i(p)(v_p)=d\pi^i(p)(v_p)=D\pi^i(p)(v)=v^i$$

($\pi^i$ is the $i$'s component of $x=(x^1,...,x^n)$).

Why does $D\pi^i(p)(v)=v^i$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\pi^i\colon\Bbb R^n\to\Bbb R$ is projection onto the $i$th coordinate. As such it is a linear map, and the derivative of a linear map (at any point) is itself. Of course, $\pi^i(v) = v^i$, by definition.